# Jquery visibility toggle not working

Tags: jquery, visibility

Just a quick question, can someone tell me where this is going wrong, I'm trying to toggle visibility of a class but I can't restore its visibility. Hiding it is fine:

```
if($(".ball").is(':visible') == true) { 
   $(".ball").css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'}); 
} else { 
    $(".ball").css({ 'visibility': 'visible'}); 
}
```

I can't use toggle as I need the class to remain but not be seen, toggle will mess with formatting.

Help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all elements with the `ball` class and then determine where or not it is hidden:

```
$(".ball").each(function() {
    var ball = $(this);
    if (ball.css("visibility") === "hidden")
        ball.css("visibility", "visible");
    else
        ball.css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: No worries. It's not about getting there first but making sure the correct answers are available. Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 6):

The selector ":visible" does not work with **visibility**, only with **display**

Here is a fragment of the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/:

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

Try this:

```
if($(".ball").css("visibility") == "visible") { 
    $(".ball").css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'}); 
} else { 
    $(".ball").css({ 'visibility': 'visible'}); 
}
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/eGVWM/2/

Comment: +1 Good explanation.  @mao: Also, you should reuse your selected `$(".ball")`, rather than selecting it three times.  Something like: `var ball = $(".ball"); if(ball.css("visibility") == "visible") { ...`

Answer (score 1):

`$(".ball").toggle();` will toggle too, but behaves using `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".ball").is(':visible') == true) { 
  $(".ball").hide();
 };
```

May not be what you are after but it will hide the elements with 'ball' class

Comment: Yea, thats the same as toggle, afaik it effectively makes it 0 size instead of hiding visibility which is what I need. Thanks though.